# Cannot navigate another component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I have a List and Details components in an application and I am trying to navigate to Details component by passing `id` parameter. However, there is not a reponse or error when calling the following method. I also share the `routing.module`:

***routing.module***

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ListComponent,
    data: {...}
  },
  {
    path: '/details/:id',
    component: DetailsComponent,
    data: {...}
  }
];
```

***list.component***

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

details(id) {
  // the code hits here and get the id parameter correctly
  this.router.navigate(['/details'], {
    queryParams: { id: id }
  });
}
```

***details.component***

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.paramMap
    .subscribe(params => {
      let id = +params.get('id');
    });
}
```

So, what is wrong with this approach? The `ngOnInit` block of the details page is not fired.

Comment: `this.router.navigate(['/details/'+id])`

Comment: Thanks, voted up. What about passing this received `id` value to the child component (that is called via ``<router-outlet></router-outlet>`)?

Comment: an element into <router-outlet> is **not** a children, if you has a children use `@Input()`:https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

Comment: Yes, what about passing data to a component in `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`?

Answer (score 2):

In your route, you have specified `'/details/:id'` where ID is `Router Param` not a `Query Param`.

Thus, if you want to navigate to that url, use this instead:

**ListComponent**

```
this.router.navigate(['/details', id])
```

**DetailsComponent**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}


ngOnInit() {
   const id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;      // Fetch the ID from your
                                                  // current route "/details/:id"
}
```

or you can also do it this way

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => console.log(params.id))
}
```

More info on [Angular Router Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work, voted up. What about passing this received id value to a component in `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` ?

Comment: I'm quite not sure if I follow, but I have updated my answer based on what I have understood from your question

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `queryParamsHandling: 'merge'` to your code

```
details(id) {
  // the code hits here and get the id parameter correctly
  this.router.navigate(['/details'], {
  queryParams: { id: id },
  queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello in the app component.html

Please add

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: What about passing this received id value to a component in `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` ?